# How to create multi language enum in Android?

Tags: java, android, enums, internationalization

I'm using this enum:

```java
public enum FruitType{
    APPLE("1", "Apple"),
    ORANGE("2", "Orange"),
    BANANA("3", "Banana"),
    UNKNOWN("0", "UNKNOWN");

    private static final Map<String, FruitType> lookup
            = new HashMap<String, FruitType>();

    static {
        for ( FruitType s : EnumSet.allOf(FruitType.class) )
            lookup.put(s.getCode(), s);
    }

    public static FruitType getById(String id) {
        for(FruitType e : values()) {
            if(e.Code.equals(id)) return e;
        }
        return UNKNOWN;
    }

    private String Code;
    private String Text;

    FruitType( String Code, String Text ) {
        this.Code = Code;
        this.Text = Text;
    }

    public final String getCode() {
        return Code;
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a number (0-3) from a server, and I want to use a localized string for using the enum's getText() method.

```java
textView.setText(FruitType.getById(data.getFruitType()).getText())
```

How can I use string resources in the enum's "Text" instead of static text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android has already provided you with a pretty solid approach to solve i18n through its resource dir structure.

In your case, it's probably better *not* to have `FruitType` directly relate to a string, but rather a res ID:

```
public enum FruitType {

    APPLE("1", R.string.apple),
    ORANGE("2", R.string.orange),
    BANANA("3", R.string.banana),
    UNKNOWN("0", R.string.unknown_fruit);

    ...
}
```

You can then define a convenience method to obtain the actual string value of these enums like so:

```
public enum FruitType {

    ...

    public final String getText(Context context) {
       return context.getString(this.Text)
    }

    ...
}
```

Now we have this setup, just proceed with the usual drill of declaring multiple `strings.xml` according to your target locale:

```
../src/main/res
├── values
│   └── strings.xml
├── values-in
│   └── strings.xml
├── values-th
│   └── strings.xml
└── values-vi
    └── strings.xml
```